# How are melatonin levels measured in humans?

Tags: human-biology, endocrinology, sleep

**I'm wondering how it is possible to measure diurnal variations of melatonin levels in humans.** I keep reading that there should be a large difference in amplitude between melatonin levels measured at night and in the middle of the day.

Have there been any studies of melatonin levels in humans where I can take a look at the methods they used for this kind of testing and/or see sample results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the **analytics of melatonin** I have here a german language text by the RKI with references. Translated quote:

> Assay of melatonin is done by serum or sputum using RIA or ELISA.
>   Alternatively, to infer the nightly amount of melatonin secretion it
>   is possible to look for the melatonin catabolic metabolite 6-hydroxy
>   melatonin sulfate (6-OHMS) in urine.[1,2] ... standardized
>   conditions of sample taking are a must to get good results.[3,4]

Ref.:

1. [**P. Levallois, M. Dumont** et al: *Effects of electric and magnetic fields from high-power lines on female urinary excretion of 6-sulfatoxymelatonin.* In: *American journal of epidemiology.* 154, 7, October 2001, 601–609. PMID 11581093](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11581093)
2. [**D. H. Pfluger, C. E. Minder**: *Effects of exposure to 16.7 Hz magnetic fields on urinary 6-hydroxymelatonin sulfate excretion of Swiss railway workers.* In: *Journal of pineal research.* 21, 2, September 1996, 91–100. PMID 8912234](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8912234)
3. [**E. Gilad, N. Zisapel**: *High-affinity binding of melatonin to hemoglobin.* In: *Biochemical and molecular medicine.* 56, 2, December 1995, 115–120. PMID 8825074](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8825074)
4. [**D. K. Lahiri, D. Davis** et al: *Factors that influence radioimmunoassay of human plasma melatonin: a modified column procedure to eliminate interference.* In: *Biochemical medicine and metabolic biology.* 49, 1, February 1993, 36–50. PMID 8439449](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8439449)